# git and github i have a problem i hope you will help me

Tags: git, git-clean

please  help me i delete all files on my macbook by command   ( git clean -fd  )

i dont know what i do all files had deleted

i hope you help me

i dont have any idea how to fix it

the command ( git clean -fd  )

i didnt know this command will delete all filse

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+clean+undo

Comment: The bottom line is: `git clean -f` is the end of the story. Your files are gone. Restore from backup.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what else did you expect `git clean -fd` to do?

Comment: thanks guys all files had already gone